# Axios response is a String

Tags: react-native, object, axios, response

```
  const getData = () => {
    axios.get('/appdata').then(data =>
      console.log('abc', typeof (data.data)))
  }
```

it is returning a response type of String. I am not able to convert it into a JSON object. SO how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the string to be valid JSON, [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is probably what you want.

Comment: Not working as it is showing and error that expected  a string {

Comment: What's your string, then? If it's not valid JSON, there's not going to be an easy way to make parse it as such.

Comment: data is in the Object format also. I am getting it from the filename.json But i am not able to get why it is getting response as String format.